# Is HTTP Get the default method for a Web Server?

Tags: webserver

Suppose my Web Server just handles HTTP GET method request for a path "/HelpPage". If I hit it with a HTTP HEAD method request for the path "/HelpPage", what will happen?

Will the server automatically invoke the GET method handler? Or will it throw an exception?

Comment: Why not try it?  The answer is that it completely depends on your server configuration.  There is no way that we could know what will happen on your server, especially not knowing anything about it at all.

Comment: Actually I am reading a research paper "Bypassing_VBAAC_with_HTTP_Verb_Tampering" and that mentions that if servers default to HTTP Get. But I'm not sure I believe that. So asked here... hopefully somebody would know.

Comment: Prachi, then maybe the question you want to ask is, What is an HTTP server *supposed* to do with a `HEAD` request when only `GET` is supported?  In that case, I would expect something like [`405 Method Not Allowed`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.6).  But again, you'd have to take steps to ensure that your web actual server behaves the way you intent.

Comment: Upon reading further, I found a better explanation. Quoting the paper "most major web and application servers accept HEAD by default, and silently transfer all HEAD requests to the GET handler"